# can not deploy war to jboss 7 from eclipse juno

Tags: jboss7.x, eclipse-juno, jboss-tools, ubuntu-12.10

I have a question about deploying my app.war to jboss7.

My testing environment:
OS: Ubuntu 12.10
Eclipse: Eclipse Juno (Eclipse 4.2)
JBoss: JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final
JBoss Tool: JBoss Tool 4
JDK version: JDK 7


If use the default server configuration, when I start server, it will start successfully, and my app.war can be deployed normal.
[refer to this screenshot](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-yMUqZ69CoYY/UQoRuRRJQII/AAAAAAAADNg/Z0p3hymgKus/s720/default.png)

I change "Default Settings" in Deployment tab of server configuration,
choose "Use workspace metadata (does not modify JBoss deploy folder).
[refer to this screenshot](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-F8n6-aFHa-8/UQoRuWUYKbI/AAAAAAAADNk/UecBN-rkguo/s720/workspace.png)

when I start server, it still start successfully, but my app.war does not be deployed.
the console has no error log and the log's content can't find any message about my app.war

I can't understand why this happens. Could someone tell me how to solve it?
Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: This problem seems JBoss Tool's bug? (I'm not sure.)

I check the file standalone.xml, and found deployment-scanner configuration has only default deploy path, even my server instance configuration set "Use workspace metadata".

After add the real deploy directory to standalone.xml's deployment-scanner, then I start the jboss server, it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Just download jboss and configure server and right click on project properties and deployement assembly then click on add and locate the target project folder

Comment: Hi, uncer
 I think it's a bug of JBoss Tool for eclipse.
 The lastest JBoss Tool fixed this problem.